# XAMPP: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

Whenever I run XAMPP as an administrator and start MySQL, it starts to run but shuts down unexpectedly after a few seconds. My question is what's making MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

Here's what the log gives me:

> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
>   1.2.3
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
>   = 16.0M
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number
>   1835027
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet
>   started
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>   for connections. Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306 
>   mariadb.org binary distribution
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal
>   shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0
>   events
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log
>   sequence number 1835037
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe:
>   Shutdown complete

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: I'm aware that there are other posts with a similar question, but I can't seem to find a suggestion that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled it to see what it suggested that I do. I had to download the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable package and manually install the file setup_xampp.bat.  Once I did that, I opened the control panel, reinstalled the Apache and MySQL modules and successfully started them. Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of XAMPP are you using?

I'm not sure how to solve this.

Try this:
Have you tried rebooting?
Make sure your Apache server is running.
Make sure your ports are clear. (Old Skype can interfere with your ports!)

The only thing I find odd right now is that your logs have dates from 2015.

Comment: I believe the version of XAMPP that I'm using is 7.2.8 for Windows. The control panel is v3.2.2, I'm not sure if that matters since that came with the 7.2.8 download. I've tried rebooting. When I try starting the Apache server, it just says "Attempting to start Apache service..." for as long as I have it running. I'm not sure why the logs have dates from 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for your my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section configuration

If this variable exists,

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size

add a leading # and space bar to the line for the line to be ignored at startup.

shutdown/restart your system and post a current error log, please as well as your complete my.cnf or my.ini for analysis.