# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies

Tags: mysql, error-handling

Anyone can help me to solve this error, when i running MySql in xampp ?

This error message appears when I run mysql on xampp

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

logs in mysql_error

```
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.19 started; log sequence number 47063; transaction id 8
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMPP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211109 10:48:26
2021-11-09 10:48:26 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014179/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly Please at least do a search for the error message before posting a new question.

Comment: I've been looking for it, but can't find mysql_error.log with a similar message.

Comment: A search for the title of your post would have found the two posts I linked. Actually, the site displayed them to you when you wrote your question as possible duplicates, but you chose to ignore them.  There are no errors or warnings in the `mysql_error` extract you posted. The first link I provided has many suggestions as to how to troubleshoot the issue, if you read all of the posted answers.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, but why the database I created can't be opened :(, 'cleaningservice.cleaningservices' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: It can't be opened because MySQL is shutting down. A database engine that isn't running can't open databases. The first question I linked has many answers that offer troubleshooting methods to figure out why MySQL won't start. Read those answers.

Comment: MySql is running, I can open phpmyadmin, but when I want to open a table from database 'cleaningservice.cleaningservices' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: No, MySQL is not running. Did you read the words in *MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.*? What do you think *shutdown* means?

Comment: I mean now it can run, I have tried from the source you provided and it is running successfully, but after successfully running, my old database cannot be opened, even though I have copied from the old data

Comment: SUCCESSFUL, I almost deleted ibdata1, luckily it's still in the recycle bin, thank you very much for the suggestions